# Simple question

Tags: string-theory, resource-recommendations, education

How much of this can you understand and which videos or simplified ways would you suggest for me to understand more?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2rjbtsX7twc

I understood about... 3%... I guess... but LOVED it =D (one of my favorite musics... how could I not?) so I actually want to understand more of this. I love science in most of its forms (not all of the mysteries are cool... some are kind of creepy) and always could understand physics the better out of its subjects, so I always like to try and understand new things that seem complicated but am terrible at studying, specially when it comes to reading big complicated texts =.='' but when it's a video explaining the concept and giving examples I can almost instantly understand it and don't forget (with a few tests, so far, my IQ has risen from 130 to 145 in the last 4 years <.< I just have trouble concentrating... and not getting bored).

Comment: So you want a resource to explain a simplified treatment of quantum gravity?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9468/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35702/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I find it kind saddening some people seem to give -vote to me without know or noticing I've been in the Physics.se for only 2 day and am an Engineering dropout with learning disabilities and personality disorder...

I want a, or more then one, resource that can explain to me as much of what was presented in that video in a simplified way. If it teaches more, I'd like to learn more, but I want to at least be able to understand the video from beggining to the end cause I loved it and seems like a very good way to memorize the information after I learnt it...

Comment: Welcome to the mean world of science!

Comment: IMO, the *Bohemian Gravity* video is basically a collection of [buzzwords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzzword) and doesn't really *teach* anything about quantum gravity. It's nice that non-scientists got interested in it, but I don't see how it educated anyone about anything.

Comment: I don't think the purpose is to educate and I also don't want to use it to learn. Quite the opposite, really. I want to learn what those buzzword and formulas mean and use the music in a kind of "memorization technique", like mnemonics or creating an image in your mind to compress information to a single thing or logical/musical string to remember bigger information.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Richard Feynman's QED lectures](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=eLQ2atfqk2c). It's not quantum gravity yet but it might be what you're after.

Comment: thanks, I'll definitly take a look ^^ big lecture but little by little I can take it xD